# This site can’t be reached - when open Glassfish remote admin

Tags: java, glassfish-5

After starting Glassfish, the remote Glassfish site is unreachable. An address I use is 123.123.12.12:14848 (ip number changed)

> root@debian:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/bin# ./asadmin start-domain
> Waiting for domain1 to start ........... Successfully started the
> domain : domain1 domain  Location:
> /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1 Log File:
> /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/logs/server.log Admin Port:
> 14848 Command start-domain executed successfully.

Here you are a log:

> [2020-07-09T10:21:18.154-0400] [] [INFO] [NCLS-GFLAUNCHER-00005]
> [javax.enterprise.launcher] [tid: _ThreadID=1 _ThreadName=main]
> [timeMillis: 1594304478154] [levelValue: 800] [[   JVM invocation
> command line: /usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/bin/java
> -cp /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/glassfish.jar
> -XX:+UnlockDiagnosticVMOptions
> -XX:NewRatio=2
> -XX:MaxPermSize=192m
> -Xmx512m
> -javaagent:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/monitor/flashlight-agent.jar
> -client
> -Djavax.xml.accessExternalSchema=all
> -Djavax.net.ssl.trustStore=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/cacerts.jks
> -Djdk.tls.rejectClientInitiatedRenegotiation=true
> -Djdk.corba.allowOutputStreamSubclass=true
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.dir=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/autostart/
> -Dorg.glassfish.additionalOSGiBundlesToStart=org.apache.felix.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.runtime,org.apache.felix.gogo.shell,org.apache.felix.gogo.command,org.apache.felix.shell.remote,org.apache.felix.fileinstall
> -Dcom.sun.aas.installRoot=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.poll=5000
> -Djava.endorsed.dirs=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/modules/endorsed:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/endorsed
> -Djava.security.policy=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/server.policy
> -Dosgi.shell.telnet.maxconn=1
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.startTransient=true
> -Dcom.sun.enterprise.config.config_environment_factory_class=com.sun.enterprise.config.serverbeans.AppserverConfigEnvironmentFactory
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.log.level=2
> -Djavax.net.ssl.keyStore=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/keystore.jks
> -Djava.security.auth.login.config=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/config/login.conf
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.disableConfigSave=false
> -Dfelix.fileinstall.bundles.new.start=true
> -Dcom.sun.aas.instanceRoot=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1
> -Dosgi.shell.telnet.port=6666
> -Dgosh.args=--nointeractive
> -Dcom.sun.enterprise.security.httpsOutboundKeyAlias=s1as
> -Dosgi.shell.telnet.ip=127.0.0.1
> -DANTLR_USE_DIRECT_CLASS_LOADING=true
> -Djava.awt.headless=true
> -Dcom.ctc.wstx.returnNullForDefaultNamespace=true
> -Djava.ext.dirs=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/lib/ext:/usr/lib/jvm/jdk1.8.0_151/jre/lib/ext:/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1/lib/ext
> -Djdbc.drivers=org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver
> -Djava.library.path=/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib:/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64:/usr/lib64:/lib64:/lib:/usr/lib
> com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.ASMain
> -upgrade false
> -domaindir /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains/domain1
> -read-stdin true
> -asadmin-args
> --host,,,localhost,,,--port,,,4848,,,--secure=false,,,--terse=false,,,--echo=false,,,--interactive=true,,,start-domain,,,--verbose=false,,,--watchdog=false,,,--debug=false,,,--domaindir,,,/opt/glassfish5/glassfish/domains,,,domain1
> -domainname domain1
> -instancename server
> -type DAS
> -verbose false
> -asadmin-classpath /opt/glassfish5/glassfish/lib/client/appserver-cli.jar
> -debug false
> -asadmin-classname com.sun.enterprise.admin.cli.AdminMain]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:28.959-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-LOGGING-00009] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=18
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488303] [timeMillis: 1594304488959] [levelValue: 800] [[   Running GlassFish Version:
> GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0.1  (build 5)]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:28.962-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-LOGGING-00010] [javax.enterprise.logging] [tid: _ThreadID=18
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488303] [timeMillis: 1594304488962] [levelValue: 800] [[   Server log file is using
> Formatter class: com.sun.enterprise.server.logging.ODLLogFormatter]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:29.417-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid:
> _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488295] [timeMillis: 1594304489417] [levelValue: 800] [[   Realm [admin-realm]
> of classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm]
> successfully created.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:29.422-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid:
> _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488295] [timeMillis: 1594304489422] [levelValue: 800] [[   Realm [file] of
> classtype [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.file.FileRealm]
> successfully created.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:29.428-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-SECURITY-01115] [javax.enterprise.system.core.security] [tid:
> _ThreadID=17 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488295] [timeMillis: 1594304489428] [levelValue: 800] [[   Realm [certificate]
> of classtype
> [com.sun.enterprise.security.auth.realm.certificate.CertificateRealm]
> successfully created.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:30.365-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] []
> [org.glassfish.ha.store.spi.BackingStoreFactoryRegistry] [tid:
> _ThreadID=20 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488343] [timeMillis: 1594304490365] [levelValue: 800] [[   Registered
> org.glassfish.ha.store.adapter.cache.ShoalBackingStoreProxy for
> persistence-type = replicated in BackingStoreFactoryRegistry]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:30.466-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [SEC-SVCS-00100]
> [javax.enterprise.security.services] [tid: _ThreadID=18
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488303] [timeMillis: 1594304490466] [levelValue: 800] [[   Authorization Service has
> successfully initialized.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.035-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=25
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304489551] [timeMillis: 1594304491035] [levelValue: 800] [[   Grizzly Framework 2.4.3 started
> in: 52ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8080]]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.079-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=25
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304489551] [timeMillis: 1594304491079] [levelValue: 800] [[   Grizzly Framework 2.4.3 started
> in: 2ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:8181]]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.111-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] []
> [org.glassfish.grizzly.config.GenericGrizzlyListener] [tid:
> _ThreadID=25 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304489551] [timeMillis: 1594304491111] [levelValue: 900] [[   HTTP/2 (enabled by
> default) is unsupported with port unification and will be disabled for
> network listener admin-listener.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.166-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=25
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304489551] [timeMillis: 1594304491166] [levelValue: 800] [[   Grizzly Framework 2.4.3 started
> in: 3ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:14848]]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.396-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-CORE-00087] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=25
> _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304489551] [timeMillis: 1594304491396] [levelValue: 800] [[   Grizzly Framework 2.4.3 started
> in: 80ms - bound to [/0.0.0.0:3700]]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:31.398-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-CORE-00017] [javax.enterprise.system.core] [tid: _ThreadID=1
> _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1594304491398] [levelValue: 800] [[   GlassFish Server Open Source Edition  5.0.1  (5) startup time : Felix
> (9,339ms), startup services(3,118ms), total(12,457ms)]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:32.439-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [jts.startup_msg]
> [javax.enterprise.system.core.transaction.com.sun.jts.CosTransactions]
> [tid: _ThreadID=19 _ThreadName=RunLevelControllerThread-1594304488341]
> [timeMillis: 1594304492439] [levelValue: 800] [[   JTS5014:
> Recoverable JTS instance, serverId = [100]]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:32.677-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO]
> [NCLS-BOOTSTRAP-00027] [javax.enterprise.bootstrap] [tid: _ThreadID=1
> _ThreadName=main] [timeMillis: 1594304492677] [levelValue: 800] [[   Registered
> com.sun.enterprise.glassfish.bootstrap.osgi.EmbeddedOSGiGlassFishImpl@4aeaadc1
> as OSGi service registration:
> org.apache.felix.framework.ServiceRegistrationImpl@263558c9.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:33.236-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] []
> [org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter] [tid: _ThreadID=15
> _ThreadName=FelixStartLevel] [timeMillis: 1594304493236] [levelValue: 800] [[   Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference
> [org.osgi.service.cm.ManagedService] as the service object could not
> be obtained.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:33.248-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] []
> [org.jvnet.hk2.osgiadapter] [tid: _ThreadID=15
> _ThreadName=FelixStartLevel] [timeMillis: 1594304493248] [levelValue: 800] [[   Skipping registration of inhabitant for service reference
> [org.osgi.service.metatype.MetaTypeProvider] as the service object
> could not be obtained.]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:34.772-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00024]
> [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=55
> _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1594304494772] [levelValue: 800] [[   Creating a SecureRMIServerSocketFactory @ 0.0.0.0 with ssl config
> = GlassFishConfigBean.org.glassfish.grizzly.config.dom.Ssl]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:34.781-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
> _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1594304494781] [levelValue: 800] [[   SSLParams
> =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@415d224e]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:34.803-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING]
> [NCLS-JMX-00020] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=55
> _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1594304494803] [levelValue: 900] [[   All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using
> SSL implementation specific defaults]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:34.812-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING]
> [NCLS-JMX-00020] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=55
> _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1594304494812] [levelValue: 900] [[   All SSL cipher suites disabled for network-listener(s).  Using
> SSL implementation specific defaults]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:34.810-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [] [] [tid:
> _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=Thread-8] [timeMillis: 1594304494810] [levelValue: 800] [[   SSLParams
> =org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.ssl.SSLParams@415d224e]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:35.187-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [INFO] [NCLS-JMX-00025]
> [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=55
> _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1594304495187] [levelValue: 800] [[   SSLServerSocket /0.0.0.0:8686 and [SSL:
> ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] created]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:35.318-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING]
> [NCLS-JMX-00007] [javax.enterprise.system.jmx] [tid: _ThreadID=55
> _ThreadName=Thread-15] [timeMillis: 1594304495318] [levelValue: 900] [[   Cannot start JMX connector JmxConnector config: { name = system,
> Protocol = rmi_jrmp, Address = 0.0.0.0, Port = 8686, AcceptAll =
> false, AuthRealmName = admin-realm, SecurityEnabled = true} due to
> exception java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:35.318-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [WARNING] []
> [sun.rmi.transport.tcp] [tid: _ThreadID=80 _ThreadName=RMI TCP
> Accept-8686] [timeMillis: 1594304495318] [levelValue: 900] [[   RMI
> TCP Accept-8686: accept loop for [SSL:
> ServerSocket[addr=/0.0.0.0,localport=8686]] throws
> java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager
> at sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:306)    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.(Handshaker.java:266)   at
> sun.security.ssl.ServerHandshaker.(ServerHandshaker.java:183)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1332)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:700)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLServerSocketImpl.accept(SSLServerSocketImpl.java:349)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.executeAcceptLoop(TCPTransport.java:400)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPTransport$AcceptLoop.run(TCPTransport.java:372)
> at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748) ]]
>
> [2020-07-09T10:21:35.390-0400] [glassfish 5.0] [SEVERE] [] [] [tid:
> _ThreadID=55 _ThreadName=Thread-9] [timeMillis: 1594304495390] [levelValue: 1000] [[   java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError:
> sun/security/ssl/HandshakeStateManager    at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.init(Handshaker.java:306)     at
> sun.security.ssl.Handshaker.(Handshaker.java:266)   at
> sun.security.ssl.ClientHandshaker.(ClientHandshaker.java:184)
> at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.initHandshaker(SSLSocketImpl.java:1339)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.doneConnect(SSLSocketImpl.java:700)
> at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(SSLSocketImpl.java:679)   at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.(SSLSocketImpl.java:432)     at
> sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketFactoryImpl.createSocket(SSLSocketFactoryImpl.java:88)
> at
> javax.rmi.ssl.SslRMIClientSocketFactory.createSocket(SslRMIClientSocketFactory.java:121)
> at sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPEndpoint.newSocket(TCPEndpoint.java:613)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.createConnection(TCPChannel.java:216)
> at
> sun.rmi.transport.tcp.TCPChannel.newConnection(TCPChannel.java:202)
> at sun.rmi.server.UnicastRef.newCall(UnicastRef.java:338)   at
> sun.rmi.registry.RegistryImpl_Stub.rebind(RegistryImpl_Stub.java:147)
> at
> com.sun.jndi.rmi.registry.RegistryContext.rebind(RegistryContext.java:175)
> at
> com.sun.jndi.toolkit.url.GenericURLContext.rebind(GenericURLContext.java:251)
> at javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)  at
> javax.naming.InitialContext.rebind(InitialContext.java:433)   at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.bind(RMIConnectorServer.java:642)
> at
> javax.management.remote.rmi.RMIConnectorServer.start(RMIConnectorServer.java:427)
> at
> org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.RMIConnectorStarter.start(RMIConnectorStarter.java:320)
> at
> org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.startConnector(JMXStartupService.java:314)
> at
> org.glassfish.admin.mbeanserver.JMXStartupService$JMXConnectorsStarterThread.run(JMXStartupService.java:346)
> ]]

How to fix it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed Glassfish 5.1 and Oracle jdk 8u241. Than it worked.